# Orbeon Form HTTP Service

Tags: orbeon

Does anyone know how to pass parameters to a `RESTFUL webservice` using the `Orbeon HTTP Service`?

I have a `RESTFUL API` at `http://localhost/RESTFUL/GETADDRESS/$parameter$.`

Sample of the `URL` is `http://localhost/RESTFUL/GETADDRESS/1234`

`Orbeon HTTP` service is unable to pass the parameter to the web service.

The Request Body is configured as `<parameter/>` and serialization is set to `XML`.

Could not use `HTML Form` as it adds a `?` to the URL which is not correct.

Anyone has any ideas to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

There is no perfect solution. But try writing the service URL as:

```
http://localhost/RESTFUL/GETADDRESS/{...expression here...}
```

where "...expression here..." should be replaced by an XPath expression pointing to the value you would like to pass. For example, if pointing to a control called `foo` in a section called `bar`, try:

```
http://localhost/RESTFUL/GETADDRESS/{/*/bar/foo}
```

I also added [this RFE](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2549).