# Adding dynamic path parameters into Orbeon Form HTTP Service

Tags: orbeon

I'm trying to add a dynamic path parameter into an HTTP service in Orbeon forms, ie call a specific URL based on the content of a form field. I know we can change the query string parameters but I need to change the URL itself - the one in this field:

[image]

I've read that this is possible in newer version of Orbeon forms by using

`{fr:control-string-value('testField')}`

but we are stuck on an older version.

I saw another question on Stack Overflow from a few years ago: [Orbeon Form HTTP Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429636/orbeon-form-http-service) where @ebruchez explained xpath is executed in the Resource URL field and gave the example:

`http://localhost/RESTFUL/GETADDRESS/{/*/bar/foo}`

However, I can't get this to work.

I have been able to successfully execute XPath, eg:

`{string-join("test", "value")}`

But I don't seem to be able to work out the correct Xpath syntax to dynamically select the value of a sample field and insert it into this box. I think I'm missing something in how I construct the XPath to retrieve the value.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
{xxf:value('testField')}
{xxf:value($testField)}
{fr:control-value($testField)}
{fr:control-value('testField')}
{xxf:property('testField')}
{xxf:property($testField)} 
{$testField}
{'testField'} 
{xxf:get-request-parameter('testField')}
{xxf:bind('testField')}
{/*/testField/}
{/*/content/testField/}
{//testField/}
{//*:testField/}
{//:testField/}
{(//testField)[1].text()}
{//form/content/testField/text()}
{(//testField)[1]/text()}
```

If anyone has any hints of advice on what I'm doing wrong or could give me an example of the syntax I put in here to retrieve a value, I'd be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AVT (Attribute Value Templates) https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/core/attribute-value-templates?q=avt. In `resource` in `<xf:submission>` or HTTP service wizard use e.g. `{instance('fr-form-instance')//url}` or if you want edit only some part of URL you can use `http://httpbin.org/{instance('fr-form-instance')//url}`. I make simple form for you https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/18c4bee259fd9f398238b3c72041ee43ea691aa7 witch save respose to dataset and have second example in `resource`.

Hope this help you

Comment: You have no idea how long I've been banging my head against a wall with this. Thank you so much!